# Exe file from windows console

Tags: windows

I have a .net application (winform) that I need to always run on the server but users are logging into the the remote session and then logging off thus closing the application.
Is there a way that I can launch it on the console remote session or make it a service?
I tried using the sc.exe command tool but the service won't run, its probably because it's not a service application.
How can I run this application?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft [KB entry 137890](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890) should help. At least it worked for us.